# SQL script with variables, how to call them from C#

Tags: c#, sql

I want to work with SQL scripts in my desktop application. But I can not write any sql
statements with parameters and call them.

```
INSERT INTO table 
VALUES (..., ..., ...)
```

Above should my SQL statement; where I want to fill the values at c# side. How should
my SQL statement; what is its notation? And how can I add at c# parameters to it.

Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

You're going to want to use parameterized SQL queries. Here's an example using the [SqlParameter](http://dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) class.

Comment: I know this. Thanks but this is not the answer of my question.
I want to use an sql-script file, your answer is using directly a string as command text.

Comment: wtf? his answer is very much correct! whether your sql-statement is written directly in code or is being read from some text files doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use external sql script files you can use SQLCMD, a command line tool available for SQL Server 2005 or later.

You can just trigger sqlcmd with Process.Start from C# and pass it the necessary parameters. [Here's an article](http://www.sqlcmd.org/sqlcmd-scripting-variables/) explaining how to pass in variables for starters.

If you are just looking for table update/inserts though I'd recommend going with SqlCommand/SqlParameters as wsanville suggested.